# how to get a moving average in sql

Tags: sql, hive

If I have data from week 1 to week 52 data and I want 4 week Moving Average with 1 week how can I make a SQL query for this? For example, for week 5 I want week1-week4 average, week6 I want week5-week8 average and so on.

I have the columns week and target_value in table A. 
Sample data is like this:

```
Week  target_value
1        20
2        10
3        10
4        20
5        60
6        20
```

So the output I want will start from week 5 as only week 1-week4 is available not before that.
Output data will look like:

```
Week   Output
5       15          (20+10+10+20)/4=15 Moving Average week1-week4

6       25          (10+10+20+60)/4=25 Moving Average week2-week5
```

The data is in hive but I can move it to oracle if it is simpler to do this there.

Comment: Please provide schema, sample data, and desired output.

Comment: which database system, which version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   Week, 
   (SELECT ISNULL(AVG(B.target_value), A.target_value)
     FROM tblA B
     WHERE (B.Week < A.Week)
     AND   B.Week >= (A.Week - 4)
   ) AS Moving_Average
FROM tblA A
```

The ISNULL keeps you from getting a null for your first week since there is no week 0.  If you want it to be null, then just leave the ISNULL function out.

If you want it to start at week 5 only, then add the following line to the end of the SQL that I wrote:

```
WHERE A.Week > 4
```

Results:

```
Week    Moving_Average
1       20
2       20
3       15
4       13
5       15
6       25
```